# form submit in a limit

Tags: php, html, limit

i want to know that
i have form of sms ... if 1 user can send 20 sms in 1 day after 20 sms from is lock or cant open then user cant access the form then next day again he is get 20 sms for 1 day means every day user send just 20 sms no more...

if any one have tell me the php script or html code for this limit form code because i add on my form 
this is my form structure of html

```
<p><label for="name">to</label><br />
   <input type="text" name="to" value="to" id="to" size="37" /></p>

<p><label for="email">from</label><br />
   <input type="text" name="from" value="from" id="from" size="37" /></p>

<p><label for="comment">message</label><br />
   <textarea name="message" rows="8" cols="35" id="message">message</textarea></p>

<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable the submit button for users who already have sent 20 sms a day. That way that user can fill the form but can't submit it.

```
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" disabled /></p>
```

Note: don't forget to have php validation on form processing page otherwise some users can try to submit form via some other possible ways.

Comment: is this possible automatic disable the send button after pressing the 20 times

Comment: @user2597055: You can keep trace in database for a user how many sms he has sent that day. if it's 20 then you show him this submit button otherwise the default one

Comment: by **automatic** you mean the code itself will do, right? place a piece of code that will check if the user has already sent 20 sms or not. By **you show him** I didn't mean, you manually show him :)

Comment: thnk you for telling me yes i want the button are disable itself after pressing 20 times

Comment: You should also check the limit after the submit of the form. A disabled submit button doesn't mean that the form can't be submitted.

Comment: @user2597055 - You will need to show some effort. This is not a rent-a-coder web site!